# Persistence and faces

Tags: java, object-persistence

I have been learning / working on J2EE projects for about 3 months now and this is what i know..

1. How to create a database in mysql (In truth i have been doing that with perl and php for 12 years)
2. I can find my way round netbeans enough to create entities from my database design and to make jsf or jsp pages and build controllers and facades to take care of simple creates deletes and updates.
3. I have successfully built manager classes to persist more complex one to many & meny to many relationships. However I am still in a sort of cgi mode were I use hidden fields to pass integer id's and do lots of queries each time a request is made.
4. I have started to learn faces and have found them a faster swanky way to work.

My question How do I persist a many to many relationship using this development model. Three days research an I can not work it out.....help

Thanks in advance and I will take all suggestions in good heart and maybe think of a new career of its really easy.